# ATL Service as an out-of-proc com

Tags: windows, com

**Background**:
I am migrating legacy code from WinXP to Win7 platform. I have a legacy ATL Win32 service hosting a COM object. I am trying to run it as an out-of-proc COM process and register it with a /RegServer option instead of /Service. Under the Run() section I have

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
_Module.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE);

Lets call this **Controller** for our discussion.

I have another Service which runs on bootup under a user account, not LocalSystem. This service does a CoCreateInstance to instantiate the controller object. When this happens an instance of the controller process is created under the user account. Lets call this service as **Service** for our discussion.

Now I have another process which also does a CoCreateInstance to instantiate the controller object. Lets call this **Agent**. This agent is supposed to be run via scripts and command line.

**Issue**: Everytime my machine boots up and both the Service and the agent have executed once, I see 2 instances of the Controller process. I don't understand why. Is it because one is a service and other is a regular process? I would like to have one instance running.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I answered my question. I seem to be a victim on session0 isolation. The instance created by the Service is running in Session0 and the instance created by the Agent is running in Session1. Hence the 2 instances. Don't know of a way to prevent this, so time to re-architect this :)